# In the alternating bit protocol, why do we need an acknowledgement number and a sequence number?

Tags: networking, wait

In class, we were learning about principles of reliable data transfer.  When we went over the alternating bit protocol, we learned that the segment had a type field (seq or ack), a sequence number and an acknowledgement number field.  I'm wondering what the purpose is of having both a sequence number and an acknowledgment number?  Couldn't we just have one field that is sequence number unless the type field denotes an acknowledgement, then we know that the number is an acknowledgement number?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence number is for outgoing packets; the acknowledgement number acknowledges the sequence number of incoming packets.

Comment: In the scenario where the receiver receives a packet with sequence number 0, couldn't the acknowledgement packet then just set the type field to designate it as an acknowledgement and then fill in 0 in the same field as the sequence number?  The sender then receives the acknowledgement and knows due to its type what it is and that that field designates the packet being acknowledged and isn't a sequence number.

Comment: @user1712917 No, because the sequence numbers are different in each direction. You can't assume that both sides send the same numbers of packets, or bytes, or whatever the sequence number counts.